# How to run and stop running Artillery.io programmatically?

Tags: node.js, artillery

I am interested in implementing artillery.io tests, but I want them to run from inside a small server app, that would receive REST calls to start and stop the load on demand. Yet most help information online are focused on CLI-based stand-alone artillery tests.

How can I be able to run and stop artillery workers from inside a program?
Granted, I can run a child process and then dismantle it, but would it be possible to natively control Atrillery via some sort of program API or REST API?